# python - connection time out Errno 110 on remote server

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am querying an api using requests through a proxy and it works fine on my local machine, but when I try to run it on the remote server it gives me the error below. From looking through other questions it seems like it may be taking too long to receive a response back and timing out. But it also says unable to create new connection in one of the errors so I'm not sure what's going on.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Python-3.8.17/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
  File "/opt/Python-3.8.17/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/opt/Python-3.8.17/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

My call is set up like so.

```
import time
import requests
import json
from authlib.jose import JsonWebSignature

proxies = {
    "http": "httpProxy",
    "https": "httpsProxy"
}

request_for_uid = {
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "uri": "/v3/reporting/devices",
        "queryString": "deviceName=" + id_number +"&select=deviceName",
        "payload": {}
    }
}
uid_request_payload_data = {
    "data": request_for_uid["request"]["payload"]
}
headers_for_uid = {
    "alg": "HS256",
    "kid": token_creds["token_id"],
    "method": request_for_uid["request"]["method"],
    "content-type": request_for_uid["request"]["contentType"],
    "uri": request_for_uid["request"]["uri"],
    "query-string": request_for_uid["request"]["queryString"],
    "issuedAt": round(time.time() * 1000)
}

jws = JsonWebSignature()
signed_for_uid = jws.serialize_compact(headers_for_uid, json.dumps(uid_request_payload_data), token_creds["token_secret"])

request_url = "https://api.us.absolute.com/jws/validate"
sess = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(total=4, backoff_factor=0.5, status_forcelist=[ 500, 502, 502, 504 ])
sess.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
uid_response = sess.post(request_url, signed_for_uid, proxies)
```

Any idea of how to resolve this?
I retested on both my local pc and the remote server and it still runs fine on my machine, but errors out on the server.

EDIT: Added code to use session and httpadapter to help with timeout issues, but it did not resolve anything and I am still getting the same error.
Is it more an issue with trying to navigate both ways through the proxy?

EDIT 2: Added Debug logging to try and get a more detailed error but the only thing printed out was `DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.us.absolute.com:443`